# How to insert an array inside an array dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, filepond

Help, I'm using filepond and I want to put the files uploaded inside an array from a declared array. I'm really sorry, my first time to use File Pond library. This is my sample code.

```
let data_to_review = []

$('.step:nth-child(1) .form-control').each(function(index, element){
   if($(element).hasClass('required')) {
       nextstep = checkForm($(element).attr('id'))
   }
   data_to_review[$(element).attr('id')] = $(element).val() 
})

$('.file_uploader').on('FilePond:addfile', function(e) {
     console.log('file added event', e);
     testData()
});

function testData() {
   let files = $('.file_uploader').filepond('getFiles');
   $(files).each(function (index) {
       data_to_review['files'][index] = files[index].file
   });
   console.log(data_to_review)
}
```

Everytime I used the code above, it gives me
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')`

My desired array will be like this: `[{ files: [ file one, file two ] }]`
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to add console.log() and see if everything is as you expect. Is index really the index? Are `Files` in `data_to_review['files']` avaible? and so on. Also `[files: [ file one, file two ]]` is not possible, It would have to be `{files: [ file one, file two ]}`

Comment: Sorry about that, I corrected it:  {files: [ file one, file two ]}

Comment: What is `data_to_review`? Does it have a key named `files` already? If not, initialize that first: `data_to_review = { files: [] }`

Comment: I think I must do an ```array.push()``` function for this, I think it only accept one value like ```data_to_review['files'] = files[index].file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{ files: [ file one, file two ] }` is not an array but an object.
Well, declare `data_to_review` as an object then set its property `files` as an array containings the files you want.

```
// declare data_to_review as an empty object
let data_to_review = {}

function test() {
     let files = $('.file_uploader').filepond('getFiles');
     data_to_review['files'] = [...files].map(f => f.file)
     console.log(data_to_review)
 }
```

Another solution is to define the `files` property when declaring `data_to_review` then push each file inside.

```
// declare data_to_review as an empty object
let data_to_review = { files: [] }

function test() {
     let files = $('.file_uploader').filepond('getFiles');
     $(files).each(function (index) {
         data_to_review['files'].push(files[index].file)
     });
     console.log(data_to_review)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an empty to array in your array of object in order to have it read by your function.